# How to generate HTTP body in Salesforce

Tags: apex, rest-api, httprequest

How do you go about creating the actual HTTP body in Apex (assuming JSON content type)?

I am trying to figure out a simple POST for the following:

```
POST https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "clientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "clientSecret": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to create a class, populate the data, then serialize it into JSON.

```
public class jsonWrapper {
        public String clientId {get; set;}
        public String clientSecret {get; set;}
}
public void callout(){
        jsonWrapper wrap = new jsonWrapper();
        wrap.clientId = '12345';
        wrap.clientSecret= '54321';
        String jsonBody = json.serialize(wrap);
        HttpResponse res;
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndPoint('https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken'); 
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        req.setBody(jsonBody);
        Http http_req = new Http();
        res = http_req.send(req);
        System.Debug(res.toString());
}
```

Read the documentation at https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts#HTTP_.28RESTful.29_Services.

Comment: BTW welcome to Salesforce SE! If this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Brad -- SFSE etiquette is to wait a decent interval and usually after OP acks that the solution is working via comments before 'encouraging them' to mark one's answer as 'solved'